# UNITY IEnumerator Function

Tags: c#, unity

I am currently using the `IEnumerator` function to pause a `for` loop, in which a ball  should move towards another game object. From my `print` statements it seems like the ball moves a little, but it's actually never reaching the object and I'm not sure why. I have never used `IEnumerator` so I'm not sure if this is a part of the issue.

```
    public IEnumerator CoUpdate(){ 
    float waitTime = 8;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
        //Finding Game Objects
        numbers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("num");
        ball = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ball");
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime * 2;

        //Picking the random cube
        index = Random.Range (0, numbers.Length);
        pickedNumber = numbers [index];

        print ("number picked");
        print (pickedNumber.name);

        print ("numer postion");
        print (pickedNumber.transform.position);

        //Moving ball to cube
        target = pickedNumber.transform;
        ball.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);

        //Checking balls position 
        print ("ball Position");
        print (ball.transform.position);

        //Pause here
        print ("PAUSE!");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);

        //Ball Returns to position
        ball.transform.position = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
        print ("ball reset");
        print (ball.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: The third last line of the loop is placing the ball at 0, 0, 0. This means the ball will never move further than Vector3.Forward * step towards the ball. Was that meant to be outside the loop?

Comment: I want the ball to go to the position then reset, so I move it back to 0,0,0

Comment: Then you'll only want to reset once it's there. You're moving by speed * Time.deltaTime * 2 units towards the target every loop( 8 seconds in this case ), However you're also resetting the balls position at the end of every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hmm I commented out the last section where the ball moves to 0, 0, 0 but it seems to just disappear. Well it moves to the same position over and over

Comment: Is speed too large?

Comment: I took out the * 2 but still seems to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your comments, I think you want a smooth movement towards the target. To do that, your step is too small, since Time.deltaTime will usually be 0.01666 at 60 FPS. So your step will actually be very small and you will move little before you reset the position again. Instead, you can use this Coroutine instead of Vector3.MoveTowards:

```
 IEnumerator MoveFromTo(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float step) {
         float t = 0;
         while (t <= 1.0f) {
             t += step; // Goes from 0 to 1, incrementing by step each time
             objectToMove.position = Vector3.Lerp(a, b, t); // Move objectToMove closer to b
             yield return null;         // Leave the routine and return here in the next frame
         }
 }
```

Call it in your Coroutine in place of Vector3.MoveTowards like this:

```
MoveFromTo(ball.transform, transform.position, target.position, step);
```